# Can I query views from a couchdb update or validate_doc_update function?

Tags: couchdb

For validating the update of a document I need the result of a view. That view generates a sum.

Can I query that view from within my validate_doc_update function, so that I can use the view result for validating the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, no you cannot. (at least not yet)

For validation functions, you only have access to the current document, the incoming document and the current user's information. (if available)

Update handlers have access to information about the incoming request as well as the current document.

Comment: My arch nemesis is right. nebenmir, a possible solution is to have a trusted account (e.g. "backgroundprocessing") and that account can fetch the view and then update your doc with the sum. The validation function can allow that trusted update. Then when other users try to update the doc, you can compare their dat against the recently-computed sum.

Comment: If I got you right, that means, I have to do it via business logic and not in DB.

Thanks guys!