# Preventing DoS and flooding

Tags: couchdb

This requires a little context, so bear with me.

Suppose you're building a chat app atop CouchDB that functioned like IRC (or Slack). There's a server and some clients. But in this case, the server and the clients each have a CouchDB database and they're all bidirectionally replicating to each other -- the clients to the server, and the server to the other clients (hub-and-spoke style). Clients send messages by writing to their local instance, which then replicates to the server and out to the other clients.

Is there any way (validation function?) to prevent hostile clients from inserting a billion records and replicating those changes up to the server and other clients? Or is it a rule that you just can't give untrusted clients write access to a CouchDB instance that replicates anywhere else?

Related:

- [couchdb validation based on content from existing documents](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13128730/341772)
- [Can I query views from a couchdb update or validate_doc_update function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6069324/341772)
- [Can local documents be disabled in CouchDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16088001/341772)

Answer (score 0):

For a rather simple defense agaist flooding, I am using the following workflow:

1. All public write access is only allowed through update functions
2. Every document insert/update gets generated a unique hash, consisting of the `req.peer` field (for the IP address) and an ISO timestamp where I cut off the final part. For example I may have 2017-11-24T14:14 as they key unique string, so that ensures that a unique key is generated every minute
3. Calculate the hash for every write request, ensure it is unique, and you will be certain a given IP would only be allowed to write once every minute.

This technique works ok for small floods, coming from a given set of IPs. For a more coordinated attack a variation (or even something else completely) might be needed.